# Ammortization Formula

Tags: apex, visualforce

I am trying to replicate the ammortization formula and finding it harder to do than in a regular programming language. How does the Math.Exp work? the documentation doesnt explain it well enough so i have no idea how it works. Does `Math.Exp(4 * 2)` denote 4^2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probably looking for [this Math method](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_math.htm#apex_System_Math_pow):

> **pow(Double, Double)**
>
> Returns the value of the first Double raised to the power of exp.
>
> public static Double pow(Double d, Double exp)

These (that can be run in the Developer Console) output the same value give or take rounding:

```
System.debug('>>> pow=' + Math.pow(2.718281828459.doubleValue(), 2.0.doubleValue()));
System.debug('>>> exp=' + Math.exp(2.0));
```

Note that Math.pow insists on its arguments being Double values and does not automatically coerce Decimal values to Double.

Comment: great thanks! thats what i was looking for now i have to typecast into doubles unfortunately.

Comment: @James OK. Please use the tick to accept answers. Looking at the questions you have asked, you have only accepted a few answers; I don't know what the average for this site is but it is probably higher than the 20-25% you are running at.

Comment: Sorry about that i will, have you experienced any calculation inaccuracies with Math.Pow? it seems that in excel i get a different number than i do on salesforce.

Comment: @James I haven't had to look too carefully. A function taking Double rather than Decimal as a parameter is not a good sign; a Decimal is typically exact - a 100 digit number is fully preserved - whereas a floating point number (such as Double) uses a limited number of bits (but is much faster to work with). But I don't have any specific information about exactly what Excel does vs exactly what Math.pow does (which is probably exactly what Java's Math.pow does http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html).

Comment: @James Stuff about floating point calculations http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20137839/math-pow-not-giving-precise-answer and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken. And in Excel: http://blogs.office.com/2008/04/10/understanding-floating-point-precision-aka-why-does-excel-give-me-seemingly-wrong-answers/.